# Samson Go Mic not working on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone

I have [Samson Go Mic](https://samsontech.com/products/microphones/usb-microphones/gomic/) USB microphone.

It was working on Windows 10, till the motherboard change. All drivers (and devices) disappear after trying reset to the backup point windows 10 function.

I update Realtek audio driver, and sound actually working (speakers), but my microphone not working on Windows 10. With Windows 7 microphone is working.
I'm running on MSI CX-61 from 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the sound panel where it shows playback/recording devices. (simply type sound after the windows key)

I have the same mic under windows 10 and I never had to deal with drivers.

I sounds that you did not do a Windows clean install after a motherboard swap, that is VERY advisable to get rid of random problems you might have.

Comment: So you suggest to refresh windows 10?

Comment: Yes, after a mobo swap, it is a good idea to fresh install the OS for getting rid of annoyances like that